# Cannot access ipv4 or lan - only ipv6 until reboot

Tags: windows-7, ipv6, ipv4

Have a computer using Windows 7 Home Premium connected to a LAN.  After approx 1-2 days it regularly loses all ipv4 connectivity, including ability to print to the networked printer, but retains ability to connect to ipv6 websites (eg. Google).

I have lived with simply rebooting every day now.  One thing I have noticed today, however, is that a print job that failed with my computer on suddenly printed upon shutting down.  That is: I requested a document to be printed and this failed, but the document started printing whilst Windows was shutting down.

I have read that ipv4/ivp6 connectivity issues are often due to firmware issues and sometimes the ISP, but this seems to be very local to me.  Anyone with similar experiences/solutions?

Perhaps the antivirus?  I am running McAfee.  I will try temporarily disabling McAfee and report on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I have suspended McAfee firewall for the past 5 days and I still have ipv4 net access.  This is the longest this computer has maintained continuous ipv4 access, so it looks like the problem has been solved.  So there you have it - if you cannot access sites outside of Google, Facebook etc and you have McAfee, it's likely to be your McAfee firewall.  The rest of my McAfee package is running.

I now need to seek a rectification to my antivirus package.  Two options - I need to update to my McAfee (but Firewall is dated as being updated Nov 2016) or go with another antivirus package.